# Gradle shows error for Support Library: "Module version com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.1 depends on libraries but is not a library itself"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

This is what my build.gradle says:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
apply from : '../gradle/checkstyle.gradle'
apply from : '../gradle/pmd.gradle'

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

But I see this compilation error:

```
Gradle 'mobi-client-connect-android-mobile' project refresh failed:
       Module version com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.1 depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
I had to downgrade the versions of support library and repository,
from:
        Android Support Repository: 6
        Android Support Library:    20
to:
        Android Support Repository: 5
        Android Support Library:    19.1

And its only possible by copying that version of 'extras' folder into your sdk's 'extras' folder.

Comment: I just avoided downgrading hassle and changed it to this: compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+' Thus far appears to be working better.

Answer (score 5):

If you have just upgraded to Android Studio 0.8.x,  Update all support library version numbers to match your build tools.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.+'
    ...
}
```

you likely want to update the build tools version

```
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

Crappy error message :-( This update has been a pain!

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, but already using 19.1.0 and the matching build tools.

Comment: @MatthewRuno I had to change a few things to get 0.8.1 to work so it could be a combination - Changed repositories to point at jcenter() rather than mvnrepo() and the gradle plugin to 0.12.+ for a start. Also invalidated caches in Android Studio and removed the old ~/.gradle directory. Feel free to edit if you find something else helps!

Comment: For me, compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.+' this thing solved the issue. as my buildToolsVersion already "19.1.0"

Answer (score 5):

I dont know how this worked!

**Original Gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.ieeekjsieit.app'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
}
```

I just changed the it to:

**New Gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.ieeekjsieit.app'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
}
```

As you can see, I forced the appcompat-v7 to use a specific version of 19.+ and not the latest!

Before changing I had this error :

```
Gradle 'org.ieeekjsieit.app' project refresh failed:
       Module version com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `support-v13:19.1.0` might have incorrect metadata. Try switching to

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'` and see if your problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the message: "Error:Module version com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.1 depends on libraries but is not a library itself"

Android Studio recommended:
support-v4 to 21.0.0-rc1
appcompat-v7 to 21.0.0-rc1

When I commented out the calls to support-v13, I came across the error is in the AndroidManifest.xml of the support libraries.
**Error:(3) Failed to parse : must be an integer number or codename.**

**/support-v4/21.0.0-rc1/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.support.v4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="L"
        android:targetSdkVersion="L" />

    <application />

</manifest>
```

I rolled my support libraries back to 19 and it fixed my problem.